# Where is my GenesisConfig entry for my config storage?

Tags: substrate

I'm trying to reconstruct the Sudo module's root key behaviour before I extend it. Following the [v1 documentation on GenesisConfig](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/runtime/types/genesisconfig-struct), I have a `config()` storage variable in my `decl_storage`:

```
    RootKey get(fn rootkey) config(): T::AccountId;
```

(in the node-template template.rs for now)

Yet, if I look at the macro-expanded output, I have no `template` item in the GenesisConfig struct, and I cannot put in an entry like the following in the chain_spec's testnet_genesis function

```
    template: Some(TemplateConfig {
        rootkey: root_key,
    }),
```

Because I get a complaint about both `template` and `TemplateConfig`, even though both are supposed to be constructed by the macro expansion.

Edit: Specifically, if it add the above with a TemplateConfig item in the `use runtime::{}` list, I am informed:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `runtime::TemplateConfig`
 --> node-template/src/chain_spec.rs:4:14
  |
4 |     SudoConfig, TemplateConfig, IndicesConfig, SystemConfig, WASM_BINARY, Signature
  |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `TemplateConfig` in the root

error[E0560]: struct `node_template_runtime::GenesisConfig` has no field named `template`
   --> node-template/src/chain_spec.rs:142:3
    |
142 |         template: Some(TemplateConfig {
    |         ^^^^^^^^ `node_template_runtime::GenesisConfig` does not have this field
    |
    = note: available fields are: `system`, `aura`, `grandpa`, `indices`, `balances`, `sudo`
```

I also don't see any template items in polkadot.js under storage, whereas I do see sudo's `key()`.

What obvious thing am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When trying to set up the genesis configuration for a runtime module you need to do the following:

1. Make sure your runtime module has "configurable storage items". This could be as simple as setting `config()` in the `decl_storage!` macro, but could also be a bit more complicated as documented here: [`decl_storage! - GenesisConfig](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/master/frame_support/macro.decl_storage.html#genesisconfig).

```rust
decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as Sudo {
        Key get(fn key) config(): T::AccountId;
        //--------------^^^^^^^^---------------
    }
}
```

This will generate a `GenesisConfig` in your module, which will be used in the next step.

2. Next you need to expose your module specific `GenesisConfig` struct to the rest of your runtime's genesis configuration by adding the `Config`/`Config<T>` item to your `construct_runtime!` macro. In this example, we use `Config<T>` because we are configuring a generic `T::AccountId`:

```rust
construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Runtime where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic
    {
        //--snip--
        TemplateModule: template::{Module, Call, Storage, Event<T>, Config<T>},
        //----------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^--
    }
}
```

This will generate an alias to your module specific `GenesisConfig` object based on the name you configured for your module (name + `Config`). In this case, the name of the object will be `TemplateModuleConfig`.

3. Finally, you need to configure this storage item in the `chain_spec.rs` file. To do this, make sure to import the `TemplateModuleConfig` item:

```rust
use node_template_runtime::{
    AccountId, AuraConfig, BalancesConfig, GenesisConfig, GrandpaConfig,
    SudoConfig, IndicesConfig, SystemConfig, WASM_BINARY, Signature,
    TemplateModuleConfig,
//--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

And then configure your genesis information:

```rust
    template: Some(TemplateModuleConfig {
        key: root_key,
    }),
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're missing `use TemplateConfig` at the beginning of your `chain_spec.rs` file. Something like this https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/8fea1dc6dd0c5547117d022fd0d1bf49868ee548/src/chain_spec.rs#L4

If this is not your issue please supply the exact error you're getting, and optionally a link to the full code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have updated the question to show the output I get in that instance. I expanded the macros because of the second error; indeed those are the fields listed in the generated struct def.

Comment: See Shawn Tabrizi's point #2. Once you add a configuration item to your template module, you need to update the line in `construct_runtime!`